# Where is the run level scripts in Manjaro and Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, runlevel

When I use debian-base OS like Ubuntu, Lubuntu or anything else, I can see runlevel scripts in `/etc/rc0.d`, `/etc/rc1.d`, `/etc/rc*.d` folders. But I can't find this folders in Manjaro and arch Linux systems. Where are these scripts in Manjaro and Arch?

Comment: It is very likely that these distros moved to `systemd` which replaces the old SysV scripts in `/etc/rc*`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I opened the "/etc/systemd" folder in my system. But I only see *.conf files and some directiories named user, system and network. I didn't see anything about script files.

Comment: Well, `systemd` is very different and you maybe should [start reading about it](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/).